# How to make HTML form execute the latest action on enter?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, form-submit

I have HTML form with `<input>` field and 2 buttons
to visit 2 different sites:

```
<form>
    <input 
        type="search" 
        name="q" 
    >   
        <button 
            type="submit" 
            formaction="https://www.example1.com/"
        >
            Action 1!
        </button>
        <button 
            type="submit" 
            formaction="https://www.example2.com"
        >
            Action 2!
        </button>       
</form>
```

When I type something in the text field and click the `Enter` key, the form always picks the first button's action.

How can I make the form remember and execute the latest action instead?

So if I click on the `Action 2!` button, then clicking the `Enter` key will always delegate to that action, until I click on the other `Action 1!` button that would change the default to that action.

Comment: What do you mean by _last action_?

Comment: @Satpal Good point, made more precise now, hopefully.

Comment: Store a variable with the formaction you want to perform, and add listener for onkeypress event to the input, if key pressed is enter then change the action of form to the action you stored in the var? Probably not the best solution but it's something...

Comment: @TomaszRadwaski Do you know any working example?